# Cancel ng-change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there a way to cancel `ng-change` event?

Actually I want to have an option in a select box but do not want user to select it but want to give a warning message and then make the previous option selected.

For that I think the best way should be if I can cancel the `ng-change` event in some way so it does not make any effect, something similar like when we return false in html `onchange` event it does not let you change the option.

I also tried to store the previous value in someway and then set that value in `ng-change` event but then found that `ng-change` doesn't pass `event` variable and so I cannot find the element triggering the event.

Any idea?

**Edit**

Something like this

```
<select ng-change="DeliveryMethodChange(item)" ng-model="item.DeliveryMethodId" ng-options="method.Key as method.Value for method in deliveryMethods">
         <option value="">(Please Select)</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$scope.DeliveryMethodChange = function(item) {

    if (item.DeliveryMethodId.toUpperCase() == 'SH') {
          // here I want to reset the value to the previously selected value
          alert('You cannot select this delivery method');
          return false;
    }

    // rest of the code

};
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code so I can help?

Comment: Actually my problem is not code specific, it is general that I want to cancel the `ng-change` event in someway

Comment: Why don't you just set some logic inside event handler instead? It really looks like a XY problem. You'd have better to provide some minimalistic sample replicating your issue and clearly explain your expected behaviour

Comment: I did, but I am not finding the way to reset the value to its old value. For that I need `select` reference inside `ng-change` as well as the last selected value.

Comment: Try using a watch on the model. There you have new and old value.

Comment: @charlietfl - My select box is inside `ng-repeat`

Comment: This whole idea doesn't seem like a very good UX. If I select something in a `<select>`as a user I expect that value to stay. If you change it back with your code me as a user won't know that and it will be confusing.

Comment: I agree, but actually the business requirement is to show the value but don't let the user select it and when they try to select it give them the warning that because of the previously selected values in the form you cannot select this value.

Answer (score 0):

It's way late, but this answer answers the question.
Essentially you can you {{value}} to refer to the current value, so pass this as an argument to your change function, and revert the field if you don't like what you did.

[Angularjs - How to cancel change event on dropdown when the confirm dialog is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051160/angularjs-how-to-cancel-change-event-on-dropdown-when-the-confirm-dialog-is-fa)

Answer (score -1):

It could be the answer;

```
$scope.DeliveryMethodChange = function(item) {

     $scope.$watch('DeliveryMethodId', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal == 'SH') {
                        item.DeliveryMethodId = oldVal;
                    }
                });
    }
```